# Look for "a,b,c" in column with data "a,z,b,c,x" with SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, full-text-search

I've been refactoring and upgrading an existing news site's data layer which I didn't developed from the start. The application is taking quite a lot of visits and after a bit of research I decided to ditch EF and go with Ado.Net / Dapper since the sql commands will never be exposed to any kind of UI layer or string manipulation.

One problem I've come up with, tough, is news tags are not normalized in the database and stored as a comma seperated string in News table and there is a front-end functionality which requires "related news" to be shown to the user.

So I need to search *any* occurences of a comma delimited string values in a table column that also contains comma delimited string values.

I've come up with the following query in sql management studio but it (obviously) takes a good time to return the results. Is there a way to do this operation better? I don't have expert knowledge in SQL so with my knowledge this is the query working at the moment:

```
-- I'm declaring this variable only for testing. In reality, @Tags should also be a query
-- which returns the set of tags of the target news...
DECLARE @Tags nvarchar(MAX)
Select @Tags = Tags FROM News WHERE Id = 7978 -- No idea where / how to include this query
-- in the actual search query :/

-- dbo.Split is a table valued function that takes a comma delimited nvarchar as parameter
-- and returns table(Id int, Data nvarchar, Order int) with the seperated values of the CSV
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10 N.Id, N.Title, N.CreatedAt From News N
CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(N.Tags) B
WHERE B.Data IN
(
    SELECT C.Data FROM dbo.Split(@Tags) C
)
ORDER BY N.CreatedAt DESC, N.Id DESC
```

I have full text index enabled and set for "Tags" column in the News table, but couldn't think of a proper query to use benefits of it.

SQL Server version: 2008 R2

This query supposed to supply an `IEnumerable<NewsDto> GetRelatedNews(int targetNewsId)` api method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further research didn't produce any alternatives to what I gave as an example in my original post. So I decided to go with that query and turn it into a stored procedure.

It takes 3 seconds to return all results and in my Web project I'm calling this method via ajax and caching the results to prevent running the same SP for every request.

Overall it doesn't impact my WebUI performance since it loads related news asynchronously and uses cached result if any exists.

Answer (score 0):

Will you try following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10 n.Id, n.Title, n.CreatedAt
FROM dbo.Split(@Tags) c
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT id, Title, CreatedAt
    FROM News 
    WHERE CONTAINS(Tags, c.Data) //THIS SHOULD MAKE USE OF FT
) n
```

But one drawback is that it may get all top 10 news from the first tag.

Comment: Parser gives two errors: c is specified multiple times in a from clause, and, multi-part identifier n could not be bound. Note that I just copied your query and left only the decleration and assignment of @Tags.